# PHP : How can I check Array in array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have 1 array, and the this array contains is an array also for each element. ex:

```
$arraycenter = array(
                      array('a','b','c','d'),  //array1
                      array('e','d','f','g'),  //array2
                      array('a','b','c','d'),  //array3
                      array('e','d','f','g'),   //array4
                      array(.............. ),  //.....
                      array(...............);  //array++
```

How can check array1 & array3 is the same, and array2 & array 4 is the same?

Comment: I doubt `$a[1] == $a[3] && $a[2] == $a[4]` is the answer you're looking for. Form a better question, one that expresses what you're really trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array_diff

```
if (array_diff($arraycenter[1], $arraycenter[2], $arraycenter[3]))
    // Do something
```

Or (if you don't know how many items need to be checked) you can use array_filter

```
$array_center = array_filter($array_center, function($value) use(&$array_center) 
 {
    return array_diff($array_center[1], $value);
 }
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, but I want to know if anyone of them are in the same value! during the check progress! then do some action...! how about that?

Comment: You can use [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) to do the same thing

Comment: how can use array_walk in 2 array dimension like my case mate? I don't understand actually using array walk. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `===` operator:

```
if ($arraycenter[0] === $arraycenter[2] && $arraycenter[1] === $arraycenter[3]) {
    // do stuff...
}
```

Comment: Hi mate, Mureinik, thank for reply, ok if the $arraycenter is only 4 array, but how if $arraycenter is dynamic also? I mean $arraycenter is dynamic.

Comment: @MikeAmq can you clarify the requirement about $arraycenter being dynamic? For instance, what would you want to check if its has six elements? Or seven?

Comment: the elements of $arraycenter is dynamic, mate, basing on the ellement $arraycenter length. but how if I do not sure the length? please check the post update, I just update the post.

Comment: @MikeAmq your question still talks about checking the first and third elements and the second and forth. I'm not clear on what you'd want to check if there are more elements. Can you give an example with more elements?

Comment: yeah Mate, yes actually i want to check whether it exists in all the same or not, mate :)

Comment: if any each of them, are in the same or not mate..! for doing some action...!